# Linux - how can I tar only directories that contain specific files?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, find, tar

I've searched and tried myself now for a few hours and just can't seem to quite get through the last step.

What I need to do is search through two layers of subdirectories for all .xml files, and any first layer subdirectory that contains a .xml file is a subdirectory I want to tar - however I can't get the sed command right so I haven't even moved on to figuring out the tar command.
Example, if i have the following files

```
/dir1/subdir1/file.xml
/dir2/subdir2/file.xml
/dir3/file.doc
/dir4/file.xml
/dir5/subdir1/file.doc
```

I only want to end up tarring dir1, dir2, and dir4; the .xml files could be within 1 or 2 layers deep and i don't want to tar directories that don't have a .xml file.

I think the solution is a combination of find __ | sed ____ | tar, however I can't get the sed command right. So far the find __ | sed ___ command I have is:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '.xml' | sed 's/*.xml//'
```

which finds all '.xml' files within the next 2 sub-directories and then prints a list of the path to that file sans the '.xml' extension.  This is the closest i've gotten even though what i really need is without the file all together.

Even just helping with the sed command would be helpful! thank you!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You're right - i meant to post this on stack exchange, is there any way I can move it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `sed`, you can use `cut`:

```
find -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.xml" | cut -d / -f 2 | sort -u | xargs tar -cf stuff.tar
```

The `sort -u` is needed so you don't include a directory more than once when it contains more than one XML file.

Comment: The first three segments of this are exactly what I want, thanks! Can you explain what the tar command does? (I'm afraid to run it since I have limited storage space).  I'm hoping each folder gets tar'd with it's own name versus me having to manually name it - it appears here that I have to mannually name it (i.e. via your "stuff.tar" portion)

Comment: @Sam I thought you wanted a single tarball with all the directories. `stuff.tar` is the name of the tarball that will be created. The names of the directories that are included in the tarball are automatically passed in by `xargs`.

Comment: Gotch ya! Thanks for explaining.  I think this actually will work better since the data is going on tape storage anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose find will give you proper list, and you don't need to sed, just using dirname is enough.

Try something like `find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*.xml' | xargs dirname`
 and pipe it again to tar.